# Dealing With Large If Statements? - PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a script i'm working on that has 2 basic input tags. One of them named 'Season' other named 'Episode' when you select a season e.g. Season 2 it will reveal the Episode input tag by using Java-script to change the display style to block. You then do the same with Episode input tag but this time it displays a Button with a on-click event link.

Im trying to make it a ton more easier to add the link to each button. Currently I have it setup so that there are 30 'dls1e' parts in MySQL which contains the Download links.

The issue im having is its a huge pain having to make a ton of if statements for this.

Code:

```
//Season Changer Script
if($seasonscript!='') {echo $seasonscript;} else {echo '<p>An error has occured. (Error: #01 - No season script is present for this show.)</p>';}

//Episodes Script
if($episodescript!='') {echo $episodescript;} else {echo '<p>An error has occured. (Error: #02 - No episode script is present for this show.)</p>';}

//720p Download Buttons
//if($l720p!='') {echo $l720p;}

?>

<form method="POST" action="" class="pure-form" style="color: #000;">

<fieldset class="pure-group">
<h2 style="color: #fff; display:inline-block">Season</h2>
<select style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;" id="selectseason" onchange="javascript:seasonChange()">
<?php if($seasoncount!='') {echo $seasoncount;} else {echo '<option>There are no seasons ready for this TV Show.</option>';} ?>
</select>
</fieldset>

<?php
if($episodescript = 'Season1') {
echo '<fieldset style="display: none;" id="season1episodes" class="pure-group">';
echo '<h2 style="color: #fff; display:inline-block">Episode</h2>';
echo '<select style="display: inline-block; width: 50%;" id="selectseason1episode" onload="javascript:season1episodesChange()" onchange="javascript:season1episodesChange()">'.$season1episodes.'</select>';
echo '<span id="s1buttons">';

if($dls1e1 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode1" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e1.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 1</button>';}

if($dls1e2 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode2" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e2.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 2</button>';}

if($dls1e3 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode3" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e3.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 3</button>';}

if($dls1e4 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode4" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e4.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 4</button>';}

if($dls1e5 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode5" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e5.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 5</button>';}

if($dls1e6 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode6" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e6.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 6</button>';}

if($dls1e7 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode7" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e7.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 7</button>';}

if($dls1e8 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode8" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e8.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 8</button>';}

if($dls1e9 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode9" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e9.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 9</button>';}

if($dls1e10 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode10" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e10.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 10</button>';}

if($dls1e11 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode11" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e11.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 11</button>';}

if($dls1e12 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode12" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e12.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 12</button>';}

if($dls1e13 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode13" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e13.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 13</button>';}

if($dls1e14 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode14" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e14.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 14</button>';}

if($dls1e15 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode15" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e15.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 15</button>';}

if($dls1e16 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode16" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e16.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 16</button>';}

if($dls1e17 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode17" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e17.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 17</button>';}

if($dls1e18 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode18" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e18.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 18</button>';}

if($dls1e19 != '') {echo '<button id="season1episode19" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e19.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode 19</button>';}

echo '</span></fieldset>';
}
?>
</form>
```

As you can see from the code, im forced to have 30 if statements just to check if theres a download link inside the dls1e and if there is then it outputs a button and appends a link to it.

Is there any way to get it to check using less if statements or able to use less MySQL columns for applying different links to different buttons?

I had a script that did this for me about 2-3 months ago but not sure what happened to it and I cant find where I got it from.

I'd be very appreciated if anyone could help me out with this.

Update:
I deleted 19 f the dls1e's I had and renamed the 30th one I kept to s1episodes. As shown here: https://gyazo.com/aed3cd627f173f01c8871dd64ae7aa16

I then used explode() on s1episodes:

```
$s1ep = explode("~", $s1episodes);
```

So now s1ep[0] is link 1 (dls1e1), s1ep[1] is link 2 (dls1e2) and so on all I need now is a loop to basically do what the 19 if statements are doing.

Comment: You could use one column and put a serialized array in there with all the infos and then loop over it.

Comment: Or you could make one table for exactly that purpose, you just need an unique id to connect the entries to one row in your series table.

Comment: What do you mean by Serialized? I do understand about having an array which would probably work fine. But i'll wait until anyone else has any solutions.

Comment: http://php.net/serialize http://php.net/unserialize

Comment: You should figure out how loops work :-)

Comment: Not sure what serialize will do for me though as i'm not trying to insert anything into a Database from a Page, Im just manually putting the urls in from PhpMyAdmin then trying to load all dls1e's that has a link set in MySQL. If theres a link output a button.

Comment: You should put all dls1e's in an array and put that array serialized in one column.

Comment: But I cant rlly explain why that wont work the page im doing all this in uses GET to do something like: example.com?columid=2 which will then load stuff from that column row or whatever so if I try to make a page that serializes and posts to one Column it would just not work I need a way to just manually put an array in the column from phpmyadmin then somehow load it from the page and extract each link in order and put it in the onclick="" for each button accordingly. Understand what I mean?

Comment: Would using explode be a good way? Since I dont want to exactly post stuff to the DB I just want to extract, Wouldnt explode() be the way to go? Like I could maybe use a - to explode from and use a while loop maybe to extract and order. Any idea how I would go around with the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I didn't understand what is your problem :-( :-)

But to get rid of 19 `IF`s (why did you write 30 in your post?) you can replace it with regular loop:

```
for ($i=1;$i<=19; $i++) {
    if(${'dls1e'.$i} != '') {
       echo '<button id="season1episode'.$i.'" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$dls1e.$i.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode '.$i.'</button>';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
foreach ($s1ep as $key=>$value ) {
   echo '<button id="season1episode'.($key+1).'" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$value.'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode '.($key+1).'</button>';
}
```

Comment: I had only 19 in just for an example of how big it could get xD didnt want to just spam it in. Anyway this would probably work but ive found a different approach but you seem to know about loops so please help me out with this approach. Basically I now found that if I use explode() I can make it from 30 dls1e<x>'s to just 1 (WHich I renamed to s1episodes) and then I could do s1ep[0] which would give me the link for episode 1 then do s1ep[1] that gives me link 2 e.t.c but I still have to use 30 if's can you code up a loop for this? Code: `$s1ep = explode("~", $s1episodes);`

Comment: I am sorry, but I still understand nothing. Could you try to update your post with some example of php code, to describe an issue you have.

Comment: I removed 29 of the 30 dls1e's from mysql and then renamed the last one to s1episodes. Then put all my links in it and seperated with a ~. I applied explode() to this and now s1ep[0] is the first link and s1ep[1] is the next link e.t.c so now how would I do something like: `for ($i=0;$i<=30; $i++) {
    if(${'s1ep['.$i.']'} != '') {
       echo '<button id="season1episode'.$i.'" type="button" onclick="window.open(\'http://example.com?url='.$s1ep[.$i.].'&ref='.$imdbid.'\');" class="pure-button pure-input-1-2 pure-button-primary" style="display: none;">Download Episode '.$i.'</button>';
    }
}`

Comment: **1st** - I've asked you to edit/update your post, not to comment here. **2nd** why did you change your code to `explode` something? **3rd** - I see no `explode` in your code you posted originally. **4th** I **guess** you've changed variable *$dls1e1* to *$s1p[1]*, *$dls1e2* to *$s1p[2]* and so on. If my guess is correct - - tell me, I will update my answer a bit.

Comment: 1st - Sorry i'll update it in sec 2nd because it was a pain having 30 sql columns for soemthing this simple, using explode allows me to use 1 column making it much easier. 3rd Yes I only just added it in ill update that in sec 4th No not exactly I deleted dls1e2 - dls1e30 and only renamed dls1e1 to s1episodes and then used explode on it making our new variable s1ep not s1p and since its an array from how explode works s1ep[0] is basically dls1ep1 and s1ep[1] is dls1ep2. Get it?

Comment: No, post your database schema, post some data samples, post working php code and try to describe what exactly you have to fix then.

Comment: No it doesn't. Hope you are really just beginner. The way you ask questions is really not clear. Check my update. I am done here.

Comment: Working perfectly :D Thank you for the help!

Comment: Good luck with your project!